# OBJECT to XML and XML to OBJECT with JAXBContext and Marshaller

Tags: java, xml, jaxb

```
    BufferedWriter out = new BufferedWriter(fstream);
    try {
        JAXBContext context = JAXBContext.newInstance(NarociloType.class);

        Marshaller m = context.createMarshaller();
        m.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, true);

        m.marshal(parameters, out);
        out.newLine();
    } catch (PropertyException pe) {
        // TODO: Add catch code
        pe.printStackTrace();
    } catch (JAXBException jaxbe) {
        // TODO: Add catch code
        jaxbe.printStackTrace();
    }
```

but empty types are not stored into XML. For example:

```
NarociloType.date = null
```

but i can not see in xml `<date></date>`. 
JAXB marshalling does not create empty element for null values

Can i also change XML to object back with JAXBContext?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Note:**  The following example works in [EclipseLink JAXB (MOXy)](http://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/moxy.php), but not the JAXB reference implementation included in Java SE 6.

If you are using MOXy as your JAXB provider (I'm the tech lead), then you could use an `XmlAdapter` for this use case.

**DateAdatper**

```
import java.util.Date;

import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlValue;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.adapters.XmlAdapter;
import forum235.DateAdapter.AdaptedDate;

public class DateAdapter extends XmlAdapter<AdaptedDate, Date> {

    @Override
    public Date unmarshal(AdaptedDate adaptedDate) throws Exception {
        return adaptedDate.date;
    }

    @Override
    public AdaptedDate marshal(Date date) throws Exception {
        AdaptedDate adaptedDate = new AdaptedDate();
        adaptedDate.date = date;
        return adaptedDate;
    }

    static class AdaptedDate {
        @XmlValue
        public Date date;
    }

}
```

**Root**

```
import java.util.Date;

import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.adapters.XmlJavaTypeAdapter;

@XmlRootElement
public class Root {

    private Date date;

    @XmlJavaTypeAdapter(DateAdapter.class)
    public Date getDate() {
        return date;
    }

    public void setDate(Date date) {
        this.date = date;
    }

}
```

**Demo**

```
import java.util.Date;

import javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext;
import javax.xml.bind.Marshaller;

public class Demo {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        JAXBContext jc = JAXBContext.newInstance(Root.class);
        Marshaller marshaller = jc.createMarshaller();
        marshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, true);

        Root root = new Root();
        marshaller.marshal(root, System.out);

        root.setDate(new Date());
        marshaller.marshal(root, System.out);
    }

}
```

**Output**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root>
   <date/>
</root>
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root>
   <date>2011-06-16T09:16:09.452</date>
</root>
```

**jaxb.properties**

You use MOXy as your JAXB provider you need to provide a file called jaxb.properties in the same package as your domain classes with the following entry:

```
javax.xml.bind.context.factory=org.eclipse.persistence.jaxb.JAXBContextFactory
```

**For More Information on XmlAdapter**

- http://bdoughan.blogspot.com/2010/07/xmladapter-jaxbs-secret-weapon.html
- http://bdoughan.blogspot.com/2011/05/jaxb-and-joda-time-dates-and-times.html
- http://bdoughan.blogspot.com/2010/12/jaxb-and-immutable-objects.html
- http://bdoughan.blogspot.com/2010/12/represent-string-values-as-element.html

Comment: Hi, thx for answer but i am using JDeveloper 11g and if i use jaxb.properties still using old javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext;

Comment: @senzacionale - You will need to include the eclipselink.jar file.  You can obtain one here:  http://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/downloads/

Answer (score 0):

- You might be interested in [nillable elements](http://jaxb.java.net/nonav/2.1.3/docs/api/javax/xml/bind/annotation/XmlElement.html#nillable%28%29).
- Yes, surely you can unmarshal.

Comment: thx but i have object type which i want to convert it to XML and if is null it is not saved into XML

Comment: same problem as here http://metro.1045641.n5.nabble.com/JAXB-marshalling-does-not-create-empty-element-for-null-values-td3073245.html without answer